# Solidity keyword require (false) will run out of my gas, why?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, ether

> I meet a strange problem when I test my contract in Remix-ide + geth

- 1、I run a private chain in geth
- 2、I connect to the node with web3provider in Remix-ide
- 3、I deploy the contract like this

:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

contract aPlusb{
    function aPlusb(){}
    uint a=1;
    event happen(uint input,uint output);
    function plus(uint a,uint b) returns (uint){
        require(a==2);
        happen(a,a+1);
        return a+1;
    }
}
```

> When I test this in Remix-id Java EVM, it show this:

[image]

> But when I deploy the contract to the private chain with the
>   web3provder, and exec the func plus(), it will run out of gas like
>   this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely you are missing the byzantium opcodes in your private chain.

[Revert opcode](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-140.md) was introduced with the [Byzantium fork](https://blog.ethereum.org/2017/10/12/byzantium-hf-announcement). In chains without the fork it will behave as an invalid opcode and cause the consumption of all gas.

To enable Byzantium opcodes you have to enable them in your genesis file

```
{
    "config": {
      ...
      "byzantiumBlock": BLOCK_NUMBER
    },
    ...
}
```

You have to replace BLOCK_NUMBER by the first block you want to enable the byzantium opcodes.

Comment: Oh God,it worked. It amazing, thank you. It solves the problem which I can't find the answer in google.